# In clickhouse, how to round half up when casting to decimal

Tags: clickhouse

When I `cast(2.555555 as Decimal64(2))`, clickhouse cut off decimal part directly to 2.55, how can I round half up to 2.56? Currently I have to call round() function before casting.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CAST(round(2.555555, 2), 'Decimal64(2)') AS r

/*
┌────r─┐
│ 2.56 │
└──────┘
*/
```